# PriorityList - enqueue method error

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I wanted to write a PriorityList queue, in which all Elements underlie an order. In my case I wanted to order elements of the Type ElementType (can be anything, for testing I used integers and ordered them according to their value, starting with the highest value and ending with the lowest)

However I am at a loss at the moment finding the error in my following method. The code runs, but doesn't work as intended.

Letting the code add 3 3 4 or 3 4 5 works nicely. I get 4 3 3 and 5 4 3, exactly as it should be.
However, if I give the queue the following values: 5 3 3 4 5 4, I get : 5 3 3; 
I would expect 5 5 4 4 3 3; 
I think it is understandable, what is wrong, however I don't understand pointers well enough to fix that issue.

I would be very happy, if someone could look over the following code lines and try to figure out, what is wrong and how one could fix it. If necessary I can provide more information next morning.

```
public void enqueue(ElementType element) {
        ListNode elem = new ListNode ((ElementType)element);        
        if(head == null) {          
            head = elem;
            head.data = element;
            head.next = null;
            head.prev = null;
            tail = head;

        }
        else {  
            ListNode n = null;
            n = head;

            if(element.compareTo(head.data) > 0) {

                elem.prev = null;
                head.prev = elem; 
                elem.next = head;

                head.next = n.next; 
                head = elem;    return; 
            }
            int k = 0;  
            while(element.compareTo(n.data) <= 0 ) {
                k++;
                if(n.next !=null) {

                n = n.next; 

                 }

                else  {

                    elem.prev = n; 
                    n.next = elem;
                    tail = elem; 
                    elem.next = null;

                    return; }
            }   

            elem.prev = n.prev; 
            n.prev = elem; 
            elem.next = n; 

            } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive that a `PriorityQueue` could replace most of your code. Check out [the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

So, if `ElementType` implements `Comparable<ElementType>` or if you provide a `Comparator<ElementType>` you should be all set.

Comment: yeah, I have implemented Comparable<ElementType>
However it seems that the double linked List isn't exactly doing, what it should do and I wonder, how to fix those pointer issues.

Comment: @Imago, are you using a PriorityQueue<ElementType> as well to replace your Queue-code?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Are you using a double linked list or a PriorityQueue?

Comment: yeeah, I did, but the issue has already been resolved (thx to Laurence Gonsalves)

Answer (score 0):

As wasgren points out, this code is redundant with PriorityQueue. Perhaps you're doing this to learn about linked lists, though...

This code doesn't work because you aren't correctly linking up `elem` in your last case (the chunk of code just before the second last close brace).

Try adding this to the end of that chunk, just before those close braces:

```
elem.prev.next = elem;
```

Comment: wow. ty, that solved it. 
I am stunned, that it was actually that easy. 

yeah, I am currently learning about queues and wanted to implement the basics at least one time.

Comment: I'm glad that solved it, but keep in mind that for "real code" ( is: stuff you plan to use, rather than learn from) you're generally better off using the standard libraries. Not only is `PriorityQueue` more tested than this code, it is also far more efficient (despite the name, priority queues have a very different implementation than a normal queue).

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just use java priority queue which will do most of the job for and is very much optimised that what you have here